How to set credentials as header-args for org-babel in org files correctly?
I need to manage a few MySQL databases hosted in the cloud, and I thought of doing so in a literate programming manner.
For this, I have installed ob-sql-mode from MELPA, set org-babel-languages for sql and created an org file, setting header-args to run queries against a database in a remote server like below:
Database 1
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:sql-mode: :product mysql
:header-args:sql-mode+: :session test
:header-args:sql-mode+: :dbuser foo
:header-args:sql-mode+: :dbhost bar.com
:header-args:sql-mode+: :database baz
:header-args:sql-mode+: :dbpassword (funcall (plist-get (nth 0 (auth-source-search :host "bar" :user "foo" :require '(:secret))) :secret))
:END:

#+begin_src sql-mode
show tables;
#+end_src

I borrowed this to pick up the password from my password-store and made sure it is working as intended. I believe I am following the correct property syntax and the PROPERTIES are correctly set (C-c C-c on the PROPERTIES drawer to set header-args:sql-mode).
However, upon accepting spawning the SQL process, I am prompted for credentials again (all of them, including hostname, etc).
Why are the credentials not picked up from the drawer? How can I make it pick the credentials specified in the header args?

Are you sure ob-sql-mode supports such header args? I see a comment in the code that suggests that it does not.

The OP has opened an issue in the ob-sql-mode Github repo.

@NickD Thanks for pointing out, I did not see that myself, indeed, it seems it is not supported.
So dropping ob-sql-mode and instead using plain SQL Babel support would mean to use :header-args:sql as the header, drop the :session argument;  and the code blocks would look like #+begin_src sql.
With that, I get an error about globbing from the underlying term I use in Emacs, but that's a separate error.
Thanks!
